# Neo4j project structure

Tags: neo4j, dao

I am looking to build a relatively complex Neo4J application, which I intend to split up in two separete projects, namely frontend and backend. The frontend will be HTML5 and is not relevant for this question, the backend will have a REST interface with Jersey, but it's the structure behind that REST interface that I have questions about.

Atm, this is how I envisioned it :

```
RESTimpl <-DATA-> Service  <-DTO-> Repository <-NODE-> DAO <--> Neo4j Singleton
```

The general flow would be that the RESTimpl receives JSON and converts it to simple java objects like Strings, int, ... Those are then passed on to the service who creates a DTO with them. That DTO is passed on to the repository which performs all the DAO calls needed to write such a DTO to the database (one DTO may require several nodes and relations to be created). For DAO I was thinking of creating both a Core API and Cypher implementation, which has just very basic graph functions like creating a node, creating a relation, deleting a node, ... Methods which are useful for all repositories basically. The Neo4j singleton would then contain my GraphDatabaseService instance and some configuration stuff.

This is a relatively complex structure but I want the project to be very modular. Makes it easy to do Dependency Injection. (Everything will be written against an interface as well)

However, all the examples on the internet have a different implementation. They actually make their DTO's a wrapper around the Neo4J node or at least store the underlying node in the DTO. But it does allow for just a REST-Service-DAO structure.

But it doesn't allow me to change the repository implementations and put a different database behind the application.

What would be the "most correct way" to do what I want to do?

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Data Neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j), it could be the right solution as a starting point for creating an ORM-like abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use exactly what you've described above and I find that it works very well(one project in production, one almost there) and does not mix concerns. I don't use Spring Data but it is an option to consider.

I have defined my domain objects as standard POJO's- no Neo4j stuff in them at all. Their persistence is managed by DAO's- which contain mostly Cypher queries, and in some cases some core API work depending on complexity.

The GraphDatabase is a injected (I have two contexts- the EmbeddedGraph implementation is injected for production and the ImpermanentGraph for tests). 
A REST service is exposed using Jersey which deals with domain objects and/or DTO's. 
So Neo4j code is only seen in the persistence layer.
Got a couple of general convenience methods exposed to index/fetch by index etc.

I wouldn't go the wrap-Node way- tried it but found that it brings along its own set of problems and results in a somewhat smelly design. Looks like you're on the right track (to me at least)